# Double Linked List Deleting Node with Index C++

Tags: c++, nodes, doubly-linked-list

[enter link description here][1]So, I've been having issues with this program I'm working on. I'm new to programming, but I'm very determined in actually learning this language.

I have to use these 3 different structs in the program, so the pointers are really starting to trip me up. The function must also return the new updated `songList`. This is what what I have written so far. The problem is nothing is actually getting deleted, so it's just being overwritten within the function. If anyone could please show how you could do this it would be greatly appreciated. I've taken out a few of the functions and switch statements to condense this post. The main goal is when the remove function is selected it will ask the user to pick the index of the song it'd like to be deleted. Then when the function is called it'll take that index and the songList as parameters. It will remove the node and return the list.

Comment: And your question actually is?

Comment: My question is how do I fix the removeNode function to delete the selected node and return the updated list.

Comment: As it is this code cannot be compiled; you've taken out some code which is necessary. If you gave us a complete example it would save us a lot of work. A *minimal* complete example would be even better.

Comment: I've added the full code.

Comment: Posts that rely on links are frowned upon here. In time the link to the code (which I guess you intended to post) may be broken, and then this question will become useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to use these 3 different structs in the program, so the pointers are really starting to trip me up.

Well, for starters, in C++, you really should be using the `std::list` class, and let it manage the pointers for you.

> The function must also return the new updated `songList`.

You are not returning the updated list, you are returning the first node in the updated list.  Which in of itself is redundant, because you are returning the same field that you are then assigning the returned value back to.  The return value is not necessary, since the caller knows which list is being modified.

> The problem is nothing is actually getting deleted, so it's just being overwritten within the function.

Your `removeSong()` implemented is overly complicated for what it needs to do.  It is not managing the node pointers correctly, and it is not `delete`'ing anything from memory, either.

Also, your `f` case is not actually clearing the list at all, only deleting the first node without any regard to subsequent nodes that may be present, so they are all leaked in memory.  A proper clear algorithm needs to loop through the entire list deleting each node.

> If anyone could please show how you could do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Song
{
    int id;
    string name;
    string singerName;
};

struct SongNode
{
    Song sg;
    SongNode *previousNode;
    SongNode *nextNode;
};

struct SongDoublyLinkedList
{
    SongNode *firstElement;
    SongNode *lastElement;
};

void addSong(SongDoublyLinkedList *songList);
void displayListElements(SongDoublyLinkedList *songList);
void displayLastElement(SongDoublyLinkedList *songList);
void removeSong(SongDoublyLinkedList *songList, int index);
void clearList(SongDoublyLinkedList *songList);

int main()
{
    SongDoublyLinkedList songList;
    songList.firstElement = NULL; 
    songList.lastElement = NULL; 
    bool question = true;

    while (question == true)
    {
        char letter;
        cout << "\nEnter the letter of what you'd like to do next: " << endl;
        cout << " a = Add a New Song" << endl;
        cout << " b = Display List of Songs" << endl;
        cout << " c = Terminate Program" << endl;
        cout << " d = Display the Last Song in the List" << endl;
        cout << " e = Delete a Certain Song" << endl;
        cout << " f = Clear all Songs" << endl;
        cin >> letter;

        switch (letter)
        {
            case 'a':
            { 
                addSong(&songList);
                break;
            }

            case 'b': 
            {
                displayListElements(&songList);
                break;
            }

            case 'c':
            {
                question = false;
                break;
            }

            case 'd':
            {
                displayLastElement(&songList);
                break;
            }

            case 'e':
            {
                int indexNumber;
                cout << "Here is ";
                displayListElements(&songList);
                cout << "Enter the index of the song you'd like to delete ";
                cout << "(First Song = 0)" << endl;
                cout << "Enter Here: ";
                cin >> indexNumber;
                removeSong(&songList, indexNumber);
                break;
            }

            case 'f':
            {
                clearList(&songList);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void addSong(SongDoublyLinkedList *songList)
{
    SongNode *songTemp = new SongNode;
    songTemp->previousNode = NULL; // Note: Important!
    songTemp->nextNode = NULL; // Note: Important!

    cout << "Enter The New Song's ID: ";
    cin >> songTemp->sg.id;
    cout << "Enter The New Song's Name: ";
    cin >> songTemp->sg.name;
    cout << "Enter The Singer's Name: ";
    cin >> songTemp->sg.singerName;

    if (songList->firstElement == NULL)
        songList->firstElement = songTemp;

    if (songList->lastElement != NULL)
    {
        songList->lastElement->nextNode = songTemp;
        songTemp->previousNode = songList->lastElement;
    }

    songList->lastElement = songTemp;
}

void displayListElements(SongDoublyLinkedList *songList)
{
    cout << "Your List: " << endl;

    SongNode *temp = songList->firstElement;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << temp->sg.id << endl;
        cout << temp->sg.name << endl;
        cout << temp->sg.singerName << "\n" << endl;
        temp = temp->nextNode;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

void displayLastElement(SongDoublyLinkedList *songList)
{
    SongNode *lastSong = songList->lastElement;
    if (lastSong == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Your Song List is Empty. " << endl;
        return;
    }

    cout << "Your last song was : " << endl;
    cout << lastSong->sg.id << endl;
    cout << lastSong->sg.name << endl;
    cout << lastSong->sg.singerName << endl;
}

void removeSong(SongDoublyLinkedList *songList, int index)
{
    if (songList->firstElement == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Your Song List is Empty. " << endl;
        return;
    }

    SongNode *node = songList->firstElement;
    for(int i = 0; i < index; ++i)
    {
        node = node->nextNode;
        if (node == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Invalid index. " << endl;
            return;
        }
    }

    if (node->previousNode != NULL)
        node->previousNode->nextNode = node->nextNode;

    if (node->nextNode != NULL)
        node->nextNode->previousNode = node->previousNode;

    if (songList->firstElement == node)
        songList->firstElement = node->nextNode;

    if (songList->lastElement == node)
        songList->lastElement = node->previousNode;

    delete node;
}

void clearList(SongDoublyLinkedList *songList)
{
    SongNode *node = songList->firstElement;
    songList->firstElement = NULL;
    songList->lastElement = NULL;

    while (node != NULL)
    {
        SongNode *temp = node->nextNode;
        delete node;
        node = temp;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, using `std::list`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Song
{
    int id;
    string name;
    string singerName;
};

typedef std::list<Song> SongList;

void addSong(SongList *songList);
void displayListElements(SongList *songList);
void displayLastElement(SongList *songList);
void removeSong(SongList *songList, int index);
void clearList(SongList *songList);

int main()
{
    SongList songList;
    bool question = true;

    while (question == true)
    {
        char letter;
        cout << "\nEnter the letter of what you'd like to do next: " << endl;
        cout << " a = Add a New Song" << endl;
        cout << " b = Display List of Songs" << endl;
        cout << " c = Terminate Program" << endl;
        cout << " d = Display the Last Song in the List" << endl;
        cout << " e = Delete a Certain Song" << endl;
        cout << " f = Clear all Songs" << endl;
        cin >> letter;

        switch (letter)
        {
            case 'a':
            { 
                addSong(&songList);
                break;
            }

            case 'b': 
            {
                displayListElements(&songList);
                break;
            }

            case 'c':
            {
                question = false;
                break;
            }

            case 'd':
            {
                displayLastElement(&songList);
                break;
            }

            case 'e':
            {
                int indexNumber;
                cout << "Here is ";
                displayListElements(&songList);
                cout << "Enter the index of the song you'd like to delete ";
                cout << "(First Song = 0)" << endl;
                cout << "Enter Here: ";
                cin >> indexNumber;
                removeSong(&songList, indexNumber);
                break;
            }

            case 'f':
            {
                clearList(&songList);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void addSong(SongList *songList)
{
    Song songTemp;

    cout << "Enter The New Song's ID: ";
    cin >> songTemp.id;
    cout << "Enter The New Song's Name: ";
    cin >> songTemp.name;
    cout << "Enter The Singer's Name: ";
    cin >> songTemp.singerName;

    songList->push_back(songTemp);
}

void displayListElements(SongList *songList)
{
    cout << "Your List: " << endl;

    SongList::iterator iter = songList->begin();
    while (iter != songList->end())
    {
        cout << iter->id << endl;
        cout << iter->name << endl;
        cout << iter->singerName << "\n" << endl;
        ++iter;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

void displayLastElement(SongList *songList)
{
    if (songList->empty())
    {
        cout << "Your Song List is Empty. " << endl;
        return;
    }

    SongList::reverse_iterator iter = songList->rbegin();
    cout << "Your last song was : " << endl;
    cout << iter->id << endl;
    cout << iter->name << endl;
    cout << iter->singerName << endl;
}

void removeSong(SongList *songList, int index)
{
    if (songList->empty())
    {
        cout << "Your Song List is Empty. " << endl;
        return;
    }

    SongList::iterator iter = std::advance(songList->begin(), index);
    if (iter == songList->end())
    {
        cout << "Invalid index. " << endl;
        return;
    }

    songList->erase(iter);
}

void clearList(SongList *songList)
{
    songList->clear();
}
```

Comment: This helped out a ton! Thank you so much for this. I didn't realize it could be done like that. Lot's learned!